# Reactive Publisher openSubscription become obsolete in the future, how should I fix it?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, reactive-streams

I used the Rx Publisher and try to convert the publisher to coroutine flow in android app. But I got the following message of the used function `openSubscription()` But I cant find any replacement for this function.

> This declaration is experimental and its usage should be marked with '@kotlinx.coroutines.ObsoleteCoroutinesApi' or '@OptIn(kotlinx.coroutines.ObsoleteCoroutinesApi::class)'

```
publisher.openSubscription().receiveAsFlow()
```

Appreciate for any comment or advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation has stated the alternative to `openSubscription()` use `asFlow()`
check the [docs here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-reactive/kotlinx.coroutines.reactive/org.reactivestreams.-publisher/open-subscription.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, for some reasons, the type `Rx Publisher` came from the third party library, which I cant change currently. Would it be possible to transform Rx Publisher to coroutine flow?

Comment: Oh you r right, I forgot to add the dependency of `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactive:1.3.2` to make it work